# How to know when a specific div is hidden when page scroll up or down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div element in html page located at  position 1200px from top,now  when user scroll page down or up and the div element is showing to user then a javascript function should call . and when again the page is scrolled up/down so that div is not visible then another function must be called.

Comment: Where is your code and try?? ....

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Banana Actually I don't know how to code when a div reaches at the top of the page by page scrolling . can you do this by jquery or css ?

Comment: @Shakir.iti, a minimal effort and 2 minutes on google will give you the answer to that. please show some effort, and if you get stuck we will be happy to assist you.

Comment: Discussed at [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274630/1169519).

Comment: @Shakir.iti please don't ask us to home work for you..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if element is visible after scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery...

**Snippet:**

```
var $yourDiv = $('.your-div');

$(window).scroll(function(){
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1200) {
     $yourDiv.fadeIn();
   } else {
     $yourDiv.fadeOut();
   }
});
```

**API references:**

- http://api.jquery.com/scroll/
- http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/
- http://api.jquery.com/fadein/
- http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/gilla/rqz86z3u/2/